# debugger for managed code ( not Visual Studio )

Tags: debugging, managed-code

Normally I work with Visual Studio and also debug with visual studio. But we have virtual machines in another network there is Visual Studio not installed. And I can not remote debug. To install every time Visual Studio is in my eyes a overhead.

So I look for a small debugger for managed (c#) code that I can copy into the virtual machines to set breakpoints, step through the source code, see exceptions.

Knows someone a small debugger for managed code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **mdbg** - it is harder to use (evaluator has a strange syntax) but on the other hand it is super-lightweight. You may get it from Windows 7 SDK (I don't know why they remove it from Win 8 SDK): `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\` (x64 for 64-bit - you will need mdbg.exe and mdbgcore.dll) or compile it by yourself using source code from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2282. Make sure that you choose the correct bitness. I used it with success in production environments (also for .NET4.5 applications) and even created 2 extensions for it - maybe you will find them useful:

- http://lowleveldesign.wordpress.com/2012/02/27/mdbg-watch-trace-extension/
- http://lowleveldesign.wordpress.com/2013/12/28/injecting-code-into-net-applications/

If mdbg is not enough and you need to get deeper (analyze GC Heap, .NET iternals etc.) you probably will need to learn **windbg** (it's also xcopy deployed and you can get it from Windows Debugging Toolkit).